How to compute the differential of a function

Let $f(x,y)=x^2$  on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and let the vector field be
\begin{equation}
   X=\text{grad}f=2x\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \end{equation}
Compute the coordinate expression for $X$ in polar coordinates on some
open subset which they are defined using 11.14, and show it is not
equal to \begin{equation}
     \frac{\partial f}{\partial r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}+\frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}
 \end{equation}

By polar coordinates, $(r,\phi)$, we have with $x=r\cos\phi$ and $y=r\sin\phi$ that $f(x,y)=r^2\cos^2\phi$. Then we obtain the gradient:
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        &\text{grad}f=2r\cos^2\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-2r^2\sin\phi\cos\phi\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi} \\
        &\text{grad}f=2r\bigg(\cos^2\phi\frac{\partial}{\partial r}-r\sin\phi\cos\phi\frac{\partial }{\partial \phi}\bigg)
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
Using 11.14 ,
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p= \frac{\partial \tilde{x}^j}{\partial x^i}(p)\frac{\partial}{\partial \tilde{x}^j}\bigg|_p
\end{equation}
where $x$ in transformed form is $\tilde{x}^i=r\cos\phi$, while $y$ in  transformed form is $\tilde{x}^j=r\sin\phi$ on a subset $U=\langle0,\frac{\pi}{2}\rangle$. Let the point be at $p=(0,\frac{\pi}{2})$.
But I get (with errors!):
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial }{\partial x^i}\bigg|_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}= \frac{\partial (r^2\cos^2\phi)}{\partial r}\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg|_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}+\frac{\partial (r^2\cos^2\phi)}{\partial \phi}\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\bigg|_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
    =2r\cos^2\phi\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\bigg|_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}-2r^2\sin\phi\cos\phi\bigg(0,\frac{\pi}{2}\bigg)\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}\bigg|_{(0,\frac{\pi}{2})}
\end{equation}
But this looks quite similar to the "regular" gradient. Does this reflect the correct answer?
UPDATE
By Kooranifar's answer:
we keep $\phi=\arctan\frac{x}{y}$ and $r=\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$. Then set $\tilde{x}^j=\phi$ and $\tilde{x}^i=r$, which gives
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p=\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{\partial x}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}\bigg|_p=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=\frac{\partial \arctan{\frac{y}{x}}}{\partial x}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}
\end{equation}
Now we re-write the forms in terms of $r$ and $\phi$ and obtain:
\begin{equation}
   \frac{\partial r}{\partial x}= \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{r\cos{\phi}}{\sqrt{r^2(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2{\phi})}}=\cos\phi
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
   \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}=\frac{y}{x^2+y^2}=\frac{r\sin\phi}{r^2(\cos^2\phi+\sin^2\phi)}=\frac{\sin\phi}{r}
\end{equation}
Hence, the vector field for $f(x,y)=x^2$ for the mapping $X:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ is not in the form of the gradient.
Thanks

because the original coordinates are defined by $f(x,y)=x^2$

But $f$ makes no sense with $\partial / \partial x^i$

yes, but rcosx does, which you have to square

the change of coordinate should not be depended by a function OK? (and this problem has little to do with manifolds so please remove it from the tag)

of course it depends on the function, you cannot ignore its form in the x,y plane and it is from the book of Lee on Manifolds, so it must stay of course..

The problem arises at the time where you aim to calculate $\frac{\partial}{\partial x}$ in terms of $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}$: based on 11.14, the coefficients for $\frac{\partial}{\partial r}$ and $\frac{\partial}{\partial \phi }$ should respectively be $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$ and $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$ (in that notation $\tilde{x}^1, \tilde{x}^2$ are just $r,\phi$ in our case, and not the $x,y$ (probably you got confused here)); this rewriting is coming from the change of coordinates and has nothing to do with our function $f$. But in your calculation, you are taking the coefficients to be $\frac{\partial r^2\cos^2\phi}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial r^2\cos^2\phi}{\partial \phi}$ respectively, which are exactly $\frac{\partial f}{\partial r}, \frac{\partial f}{\partial \phi}$, i.e. the things we wanted to avoid.
A hint on how to proceed: to compute $\frac{\partial r}{\partial x}$, first write $r$ as $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ and then perform the differentiation, and then again use the change of coordinate to rewrite the expression you have in terms of $r, \phi$. Similarly you can compute $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$. And you can see the vector field is not in the gradient form.
Another, probably a bit more conceptual way of thinking about this is to note that considering the change of coordinates map $g:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb{R}^2 \setminus \{0\}$ given by $(r,\phi)\overset{g}{\mapsto}(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)=(g_1(r,\phi),g_2(r,\phi))$, its Jacobian $\mathrm{Jac}(g)$ represents the change of basis matrix from the basis $(\partial /\partial r,\partial \phi)$ to the basis $(\partial /\partial x,\partial / \partial y)$. That is, if $v=a \frac{\partial}{\partial r} + b \frac{\partial}{\partial \phi}=c \frac{\partial}{\partial x} +d \frac{\partial }{\partial y}$, then
$$ \begin{pmatrix}\frac{\partial g_1}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial g_1}{\partial \phi} \\ \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial r} & \frac{\partial g_2}{\partial \phi}\end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} a \\ b\end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} c \\ d \end{pmatrix}.$$
Here we are interested in converting in the opposite way (i.e. we would like to set $c=2x, d=0$ and solve for $a$ and $b$), so you just need to compute the inverse of this $\mathrm{Jac}(g)$ matrix. Still, both of these approaches are computing the same thing in almost the same way, and you can check that both give the same answer.

Thanks Kooranifar. See my update in the answer.

@Superunknown you’re welcome. For your edits in my answer, the first one was right, sorry I made a typo in $\partial f / \partial \phi$. But your second edit about the expression for the function $g$ is not right and what I originally wrote was correct; you would want $g$ to send a point $p$ represented as $(r,\phi)$ in the polar coordinate to the same point $p$ but instead in Cartesian coordinate, which is $(x(p), y(p))$ (you reversed the order);

but also when the domain of $g$ is in $r,\phi$ coordinates, $x,y$ are not meaningful there, so for $g(p)$ to be well-defined, we should describe it only in terms of what we’ve got in the domain, i.e. we should write $(r\cos \phi, r\sin \phi)$ instead of $(x(p), y(p))$.
